# Activate USB Speakers in KDE after login

Tags: linux, usb, speakers, kde-4

I have some USB speakers that I use with KDE under linux.

If they are plugged in when KDE starts, all works fine.  If I plug them in while KDE is already started, they are recognised by the system, this works fine:

```
$ speaker-test -D front:CARD=Device,DEV=0 -c 2
```

And the audio device shows up in phonon, but is greyed out:

[image: Phonon USB Audio greyed out]

I can log out and log in again to activate them, but this isn't a great solution for a laptop.  Does anyone know of a way to activate the speakers so I can use them without logging out each time?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used KDE in a while, but I believe it uses alsa for audio device control.

The brute force way would be to use `sudo alsa force-reload` - which will reset the audio subsystem. `sudo alsa reload` should work as well.

Looking for a one device way to do this and will update when i find one.

Comment: It does use Alsa, but alsa detects the usb speakers fine (which is why speaker-test works)